# Is it possible to visit a training session at the Danish national badminton center?

Tags: badminton, venues

I will be visiting Denmark in the summer of 2018, and I would like to attend a badminton training session in their national center. How can I arrange such a visit?

[The website](http://badmintondenmark.com/Cms/) does not have any info about it.

Comment: Why haven't you contacted the centre themselves?